# How to sum values in variable range in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table as shown below.

In column C I would like to Sum values from column A if they have the same index (column B). I would like to put sum result for all the rows if they have same index (as shown in column D).

Unfortunately the range of values with same index is variable and my macro can sum values just with 2 indexes. Can anyone help with it, please? Thanks!

[image]

```
Sub example()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim n, i As Integer
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

ws.Select

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("C3:C" & LastRow).Select
Selection.ClearContents

For i = 3 To LastRow
If Range("B" & i + 1) - Range("B" & i) = 0 Then
Range("C" & i) = Range("A" & i + 1) + Range("A" & i)
Else
Range("C" & i) = Range("C" & i - 1)
End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you use the SUMIF spreadsheet function?

Comment: Do you mean something like: "=SUMIFS(A:A;B:B;B3)" ?
I would like to integrate it in macro, because its just a part from longer code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Sub example()
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow               As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With ws.Range("C3:C" & LastRow)
        .ClearContents
        .Value = ws.Evaluate("INDEX(SUMIF(B3:B" & LastRow & ",B3:B" & LastRow & ",A3:A" & LastRow & "),)")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! In case i need to add some other conditions (to get kind of =SUMIFS), how to integrate it in this code?

Comment: It would be using SUMIFS and then similar range syntax for each range/condition pair.